# Exportar Data a Excel separando tablas en distintas hojas con php

Tags: php, excel, data

necesito exporta las información de la BD a un excel , esto debe ser mediante php , el código que tengo ahora me genera solo una hoja y hay vació toda la información pero el problema surge en que deseo que en un mismo excel se creen varias hojas donde poder exportar la diversa información a suministrar

**imagen de referencia de lo que se desea lograr:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de antemano agradecido si me pueden orientar de como hacer este procedimiento

Comment: Pues estaría bien saber que estás usando para poder ayudarte. [ask] - [tour]

Comment: por ahora estoy usando PHP Excel Header para crear el archivo pero no he encontrado como crear múltiples hojas en el mismo archivo a crear